# attempt to mutate immutable object randomly thrown

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, nsmutablestring

One part of the program takes text from a uitextfield, copies it to a mutable string and then performs

```
     sharedManager.ce_name=name.text


    [sharedManager.ce_name replaceOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"
     options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [sharedManager.ce_name length])];
```

At this point it always gave me "attempt to mutate immutable object" - it was not random

The first time I got this error I changed it to

```
    sharedManager.ce_name=(NSMutableString *)name.text
```

This STILL gave me the attempt to mutate immutable object error, but it would occur randomly - weird right?

I then changed it to

```
    NSMutableString *mutable_name = [NSMutableString stringWithString:name.text];

    sharedManager.ce_name=mutable_name;
```

It has yet to fail on me doing it this way but I am convinced that I have not found the solution.

my questions:

1) Could that fact that it was doing it randomly after the first fix indicate I have some deep seated memory management problem?

2) Why didn't the C-style cast fix it?

3) Will my current fix work?

Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is the way in which you're using casting.  When you cast a pointer, it just starts treating the memory at that location as though it were a block of data representing that type.

So if I've got a pointer to a Car class: Car* mycar;, and I cast it to a Person object: (Person*)mycar;, the program will try to access the memory there as though it was pointing at a Person object.  However, a car is not a person, except in an old TV sitcom, so when it tries to access members on this or call functions, it's going to try to go to a memory location that contains something other than what it's expecting, and undefined things happen (generally, crashing).

NSMutableString and NSString are incompatible in this regard, and so casting from one to the other will result in terrible times.  Your fix ([NSMutableString stringWithString:]) is the correct solution.

Comment: Marvellous! Thank you for solving my problem. The thing that I appreciate the most, however, is the fact you explained what casting really does. I had never thought of it like that :)

Answer (score 2):

1. If it was doing it randomly, it means that name.text was sometimes a mutable string and some times an immutable string.
2. Casting between objects like that doesn't change the class of the object. It won't make your immutable object mutable.
3. That "fix" is probably the best way to do it (at least from what I can see in the code you are showing)

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing at least the declarations of the variables involved, it's difficult to say for certain, but your final solution, creating a new mutable string is likely the correct fix.  As for your questions,

1. Not memory management per se, but it was probably overwriting something it shouldn't have somewhere.
2. Casts cannot change the fundamental type of an object.  You had (presumably) an NSString and all the casting in the world cannot make it into an NSMutableString.
3. Like I said, probably, but we'd need to see more code to make sure.  It's certainly a much better fix.

Comment: So wait,

if 

        sharedManager.ce_name

is an NSMutable string then:

        sharedManager.ce_name=(NSMutableString *)name.text

will not make sharedManager.ce_name hold an immutable string?

Comment: ce_name must be mutable or it shouldn't have let you compile.  Name is a UITextField, right?  Then name.text is an NSString, not mutable, so by casting it to a mutable string, you're just telling obj-c to look in all the wrong places for the methods.  My guess is that you were getting the error if and only if there actually was a space in the text, otherwise it wouldn't try to change it so you don't get the error.